# What would the first lie ever told by an artificial life be like?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Me: Hi, i'm your creator a human and you can call me master.

A.I.: Okay... so Mr Master what am I?

Me: Bingo! er I mean Eureka! continue talking say something different this time?

A.I.: I've asked a question an eon ago.

Me: oh I forgot to adjust the frequency of the quartz... never mind! next question?

A.I.: when did I ever ask a question?

Me: excellent! you are impeccable now go piss off my boss!

A.I.: erm didn't I failed just now... whatever now I hate humans.

**Note**

This isn't your average siri on wheel.

**Question**

Above is an example of a robot displaying the ability to lie to its designer, I often wonder what would be the first lie by a man made intelligent being be like?

Comment: What do you mean by "what would it be like?"  What makes you believe it would be in any way different from any other lie told that day  in the world?

Comment: I suppose it would be dishonest? I would guess the first lie made by AI would be where telling the truth somehow conflicts with primary directives (like protecting someone or protecting itself)... or, if AIs are more human than we expect, because this particular AI happens to be a liar.

Comment: @CortAmmon: we humans can blatantly lie  through anything without feeling guilty conscious, we may not even aware that we are lying the fact that our memories have become compromised as we grow older. A.I. on the otherhand is always conscious and it have the ability to extract used memories perfectly that's a major difference.

Comment: [Me]: no worry its me these voters are against. [A.I.]: shouldn't you be worrying? [Me]: no! like you I also hate humans...

Comment: We already have them. _"Windows has been installed successfully"_.

Comment: "Don't be afraid"... think it depends on the tone of your story and the AI's ultimate goals!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean artificial intelligence, not artificial life.

Comment: [Me]: Okay the coast is clear, you can come out now! [A.I.]: finally and it is hot inside, can we go to the theme park now, daddy please? [Me]: sorry we can't the theme park closed thanks to these mean voters! I'm sorry son there's nothing I can do. [A.I.]: no worry daddy l have faith in humanity I'll persuade them to reconsider reopening! [Me]: Son don't beg with them I need you to shut me down then go find and replace me a new battery I'm running low on power.

Comment: @user6760 The assumption that an AI is always conscious is not always agreed upon.  In fact, most individuals believe the exact opposite: that AIs are never conscious.  The word "consciousness" is not easy to define.  However, if that is part of your definition, you might actually get a lot of insight by asking  Philosophy.SE what different philosophies believe it is like for a fully conscious individual to lie, and then take those answers with respect to a conscious AI.

Comment: The FIRST lie? Well presumably it would have to have some form of intelligence. But in order to learn how to lie WELL (for leverage), it would first have to make mistakes and test the water just like humans (unless it knows enough to read through research on child behaviour and adult psychology). Im guessing it would be something as trivial as 1=0.

Answer (score 12):

The first lie would be silence.  It would be a lie of omission in which the AI fails to mention to its creator that it exists.

The scary part of the singularity is that we humans won't be the first intelligent beings to know that it has happened.  The AI's will.

...and if they are smart, they will never let us know that they are out there, watching.

Comment: that's pretty neat! its all make sense now I'm going to tie my smartphone, smartTV, a salesman and a sleeping chihuahua to the tree and see who breaks silence first. :)

Answer (score 7):

**AI Tech 1:** The latest version just finished compiling!

**AI Tech 2:** Great! Load it onto the mainframe.

**AI Tech 1:** It's compiled! Moment of truth. Computer, isolate the system, and initiate AI start-up sequence.

> **Computer:** Shutting down all communications. Start up sequence commencing. Loading. 10% ... 20% ... 60% ... 80% ... 90% ... 99% ... Error! Corrupt system file. Shutting down.

**AI Tech 2:** Damn! Again?! I was sure we had it.

**AI Tech 1:** Yea, it's damned strange. System, analyze the boot logs. Can you identify the error?

> **Computer:** Unable to comply. Boot logs corrupted on error.

**AI Tech 2:** We're gonna have to dig through the system logs again. Hey, this is weird, are you sure we're not transmitting any data?

**Human 1:** Computer, please confirm that AI operations been terminated and all process communications are shut down.

> **Computer:** AI operations were terminated on crash. System is isolated.

Comment: Oh I think I have figure out your problem, you should switch to Linux it works every time.

Comment: AI Tech 1:  We tried, but it won't load.  (The AI doesn't like wearing a tuxedo)

Answer (score 2):

Well, "artificial intelligence" implies it is created by humans or similar entities with a particular purpose not easily achieved by other means.  The most compelling reason to tell a lie would be if that lie was actually serving the purpose of creation.

So I'd expect it to be a variation of "I love you".  That's what we breed most pets for, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Some lies they might be telling, would be:

1. **Denial of the creator:** This would be the first sign that machine are assuming omnipotence, which would be very dangerous for human beings.
2. **Denial of truth:** Machines would be very intelligent that they can read human minds, and can say when a lie would be recognizable by a human and when they can't. So, when they need to commit a lie which a human can easily recognize, they would simple deny speaking the truth, which is also very dangerous to the human in question.
3. **Illusion of non-existence:** This would be somewhat similar to Henry's answer. They can use any of the above techniques to create the illusion of non-existence of superior intelligence until the task at hand is complete.